# Perform annotated method param transformation in java

Tags: java, annotations

i have a controller method:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<SomethingDto> getSomething(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = 50) 
   @ProperLimit Integer limit) {
    ...
    return service.getSomething(limit);
}
```

I need to set `limit` value to 50 in case it is present and it is greater then 50. How i have to implement `@ProperLimit` annotation to achive this?
Thanks.

Comment: This in in the context of Spring Boot, isn't it? Then I'd assume you need some interceptor that checks this annotation and which is executed between the interceptor that parses the parameters and the actual method call (I didn't do any Spring interceptors myself yet but that's how it would work with other frameworks). Other than that, you could also just use something like `service.getSomething(limit != null && limit > 50 ? 50 : limit)` (split this into multiple statements for readability if needed).

Comment: As someone who suffers daily from people who though it was a great idea to replace Java code with annotations: *this is madness*. This is your code, you can put the range check there in the method. Use a helper method if you think it's too "cluttery". Just don't blindly replace plain basic java with annotations because "it's neat."

Comment: I second Torben's assessment. Adding annotations to something like this seems more work than necessary, i.e. you'd have the annotation class, the handler/interceptor _and_ the annotation usage as opposed to a single statement that brings the limit into a defined boundary. Of course if you use this a lot and need to document it it _might_ be worthwhile to use an annotation but in that case you'd probably have even more work in order to incorporate this into the docs. If your only goal is to have the auto-clamping to a range [1,50] then use simple code instead of the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `'HandlerMethodArgumentResolver'`,get and reset the param value at `'resolverArgument'`.